# Regex to match last character of words having length greater than 1

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match last character of every word in a sentence in which , last character of only those words should be matched whose length is greater than 1.

For example, if sentence is:-

```
I love regex.
```

Then regex should match last character of **love** and **regex** only, i.e., **e** and **x** , not **I**.

So far i am able to match last character of every word, including those having length 1, using this regex :-

```
[a-zA-Z0-9](?= |\.|,|$)
```

But i want to match last character of only those words having length greater than 1. How can i do this?

Test link:-
https://regex101.com/r/7tnXnB/1/

Comment: does it have to be regex? you can split string into array of words and pick last letter of every word by word[word.length-1]

Comment: Do you need to account for Unicode letters, like in the word `café`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use (negated) word boundaries `\b` and `\B`:

```
\B\w\b
```

Here `\w` matches a word character, `\w\b` asserts a word boundary (therefore it'll only match the last character in a word), and `\B` asserts that there is no word boundary *before* this character.

Comment: Only thing to mention is the fact, that `\w` includes the underscore - which should not be an issue in normal text - but one never knows :)

Comment: Sweet and simple. Excellent. It worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[A-Z0-9a-z]{2,}
```

The {2,) makes sure it'll only get characters 2 or more of length

Comment: this is not what he wanted....it match word with two or more chars....but he wanted just match last char of word which has length more than 1

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you, although I'm sure there is a shorthanded version of this

```
[a-zA-Z0-9](?= [a-zA-Z0-9]|\.|,|$)
```

Edit:

```
\w(?= \w|\.|,|$)
```